# Salesforce1 Mobile - using sandbox and production

Tags: salesforce1-app, ios

I am currently able to setup Salesforce1 Mobile (S1M) to switch between production orgs, however I am unable to setup S1M to retain both my sandbox and my production logins so that I can switch between them, is it possible to switch between production and sandbox for the same org from within the app or is that a limitation?

Comment: Hi bartley, it is limitation you can say. I would suggest to post idea, your idea is cool...